# $_POST will convert from utf-8 to Ã¤ Ã¶ Ã¼ etc

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, mojibake

I am new here, so I apologize if I am doing anything wrong.

I have a form which submits user input onto another page. User is expected to type ä, ö, é, etc... I have placed all of the following in the document:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
<form action="whatever.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

I even tried:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

When the other page loads, I need to check what the user input with something like:

```
if ( $_POST['field'] == $check ) {
  ...
}
```

But if he inputs something like 'München', PHP will compare 'MÃ¼nchen' with 'München' and will never trigger TRUE even though it should. Since it is specified UTF-8 everywhere, I am guessing that the server is converting to something else (Windows-1252 as I read on another thread) because it does not support or is not configured to UTF-8. I am using Apache on a local server before I load into production; I have not changed (and don't know how to) any of the default settings. I've been working on a Windows 7, editing with Notepad++ enconding my files in ANSI. If I `bin2hex('München')` I get '4dc3bc6e6368656e'.

If I `echo $_POST['field'];` it displays 'München' correctly.

I have researched everywhere for an explanation, all I find is that I should include those tags/headings I already have.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are facing many different problems at the same, let's start with the simplest one.

Problem 1) You say that `echo $_POST['field'];` will display it correctly? What do you mean with "display"? It can be displayed correctly in two cases:

- either the field is in UTF-8 and your page has been declared as UTF-8 and the browser is displaying it as UTF-8 or,
- the field is in Latin-1 and the browser has decided (through the auto-detection heuristics) that your page is in Latin-1.

So, the fact that `echo $_POST['field'];` is correct tells you nothing.

Problem 2) You are using

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Is this PHP code? If it is, it will be an error because the header must be set before sending out any byte. If you do this you will not set the `Content-Type` header and PHP should generate a warning.

Problem 3) You are using

```
<form action="whatever.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Some browsers (IE, mostly) ignore `accept-charset` if they can coerce the data to be sent in ASCII or ISO Latin-1. So the data will be in UTF-8 and declared as ISO Latin-1 or ISO Latin-1 and sent as ISO Latin-1 (but this second case is not your case).

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547004/449288 to see how to solve this problem.

Problem 4) Which strings are you comparing? For example, if you have

```
$city = "München"
$_POST['city'] == $city
```

The result of this code will depend on the encoding of the PHP file. If the file is encoded in ISO Latin-1 and the `$_POST` correctly contains UTF-8 data, the `==` will compare different bytes and will return false.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that may be helpful is in Apache, you can place a directive in your configuration file (httpd.conf) or .htacess called `AddDefaultCharset`. It looks like this:

`AddDefaultCharset utf-8`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset

That will override any other default charsets.

Answer (score 3):

I changed "mbstring.detect_order = pass" in my php.ini file and i worked

Answer (score 0):

I've used Unicode characters in my forms and file many times. I had not any problem up to now.
Try to do these steps and check the result:

1. Remove `header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');` from your HTML form codes.
2. Use your form just like `<form action="whatever.php">` without `accept-charset="UTF-8"`. (It's better to insert the method of sending data in your form tag).
3. In target page (whatever.php), insert again `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` in a `<head>` tag.

I always did my project like what I mentioned here and I did not have any problem with Unicode strings.

Comment: I also tried with only the meta tag in head, which is on every page. I guess this is what you are saying, right?

Comment: The method you suggest is very error-prone: without the correct header or `accept-charset` the browser will not know which encoding should be used for the contained forms. And if you are not adding a non-UTF8 character that is not in ISO Latin-1 in the data to be posted, IE will send the form data as ISO Latin-1, not UTF-8. Also, the Content-Type header of the response has zero influence on the way characters are sent during the POST, it only influences how the response should be decoded and displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the character encoding of the PHP file(s).

The hardcoded `München` is stored with the character encoding of the source file(s), in this case `ANSI` and when that value is compared to the UTF-8 encoded value provided in the `$_POST` variable, the two will, quite naturally, differ.

The solution to your problem is one of:

1. Serve and process content with the same encoding as that of the source file(s), in this case likely to be `windows-1252`.

   - This would, for starters, include changing the `content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"` to `content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"` whenever serving HTML data.
2. Avoid all hardcoded values that could be affected by character encoding issues between `UTF-8` and `windows-1252`, more or less only hardcode values that *only* includes English letters and numbers.

   - Any `UTF-8` values would have to be read from a source that ensures they are `UTF-8` encoded (for instance a database set to use `UTF-8` as storage encoding as well as connection encoding).
3. Wrap all hardcoded assignments in `utf8_encode()`, for instance `$value = utf8_encode ('München');`
4. Change the encoding of the source file(s) to `UTF-8`.

   - This can be accomplished in any number of ways, a decent text editor will be able to do it or the outstanding [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) can be used, especially for batch processing.

Either solution 1 or 4 would be my preferred solution, especially if multiple people are involved in the project.

As a side-note, some text editors (notably `Notepad++`) has the option of using either `UTF-8` or `UTF-8 without BOM`. The `BOM` (Byte Order Mark) is pointless in `UTF-8` and will cause problems when writing headers in PHP (most often when doing a redirect). This is because the `BOM` is right in front of the initial `<?php`, causing the server to send the `BOM` just as it would had there been any other character in front. The difference is you'd note a character in front, but the `BOM` isn't displayed.
Rule of thumb: **Always use UTF-8 without BOM.**

Comment: These days, I would hesitate to recommend ISO-8859-1 as an encoding. There are those who believe that ISO-8859-1 should be used as an alias of windows-1252, which is not true. Explicitly specifying windows-1252 is better, since there can't be confusion then.

Comment: @MrLister are you suggesting I should alter the answer and specify CP1252 instead? I'm not very familiar with Windows, but was under the impression that they used ISO-8859-1 now.

Comment: Yes, and many people think that, but it's not the case. Anyway, I believe UTF-8 would be best, while trying to not encode or decode things anywhere in the process. 8-bit character sets are on their way out.

Comment: @MrLister I've updated the answer, perhaps you'd care to share a reference?